# how to terminate a sleeping thread in pthread?

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have thread which sleeps for a long time, then wakes up to do something, then sleep again, like this:

```
while(some_condition)
{
    // do something
    sleep(1000);
}
```

How could I make this thread exit gracefully and QUICKLY?

I tried to use `pthread_cancel()`, but sleeping threads could not be canceled.
I also tried changing the condition of the while loop, but it will still take long to exit.
And I don't want to use `pthread_kill()`, since it may kill the thread when it's working.

So, are there any good ideas?

Comment: well, i think i make a mistake, sleep() is a cancel point difined by posix.1

Comment: Just a note - `pthread_kill` does not kill a thread. It sends a signal to a thread. If the action of that signal is to terminate the process (e.g. the default action of `SIGTERM`, or the unblockable action of `SIGKILL`) then it will terminate *the whole process*, not the target thread. Really the only time `pthread_kill` is useful is if you've installed an interrupting signal handler, and you want to interrupt a syscall that's blocked in a particular thread (which would be a potential solution to your question).

Comment: Why did you say that the thread could not exit quickly ? I tried this and the thread canceled immediately upon `thread_cancel`. And I was able to `pthread_join` without delay.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As an alternative to `sleep`, you could use [pthread_cond_timedwait](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html) with a 1000 ms timeout.  Then when you want to exit, signal the condition variable.

This is similar to how you might do this in C#/Java using wait and notify.

Comment: Correct.  This is the simple and non-racy way to do it.

Comment: This is correct, but cancellation is easier and perhaps slightly more efficient. Of course if you call `pthread_cancel` on the thread, you need to make sure that it can't get cancelled at a point it shouldn't. Calling `pthread_setcancelstate` to disable cancellation when the thread starts, and only enabling it just before the `sleep`, would be a safe approach.

Comment: IMO, `pthread_cancel()` may be preferable since `sleep()` is already a cancellation point. And be sure to call `pthread_cleanup_push()` and `pthread_cleanup_pop()` to set up cleanup handlers if you have allocated resources.

Comment: What is the difference between using `pthread_cond_timedwait` with 1000ms timeout and using a flag variable with 100ms sleep in regard to race condition ?

Answer (score 1):

The classic UNIX condition variable is the [self-pipe](http://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html).

```
int fds[2];
pipe2(fds, O_NONBLOCK);  // requires newish kernel and glibc; use pipe + 2*fcntl otherwise

child:
    while (some_condition) {
        // do something
        struct pollfd pd = { .fd = fds[0], .events = POLLIN };
        int rc;
        char c;
        while ((rc = poll(&pd, 1, 1000000)) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
            // not entirely correct; 1000000 should be decreased according to elapsed time when repeating after a signal interruption
            ;
        if (rc > 0 && (pd.revents & POLLIN) && read(fds[0], &c, 1) >= 0)
            break;
    }

parent:
    cancel() {
        char c = 0;
        write(fds[1], &c, 1);
    }
```

Yeah, it's a lot of fiddly (and untested) code.  You should probably just use `pthread_cond_wait`, it requires a `pthread_mutex_t` and a `pthread_cond_t` but is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use pthread_cleanup_push and pop?  Canceling with pthread_cancel doesn't work without them.  You must use them in pairs just like I did in the example below.  if you forget one it wont compile (fancy macros, one has the '{' and the other has the '}').  You can even nest different levels of cleanup/pops.  Anyway, they set a long jump point that cancel jumps to when cancel occurs (pretty cool).  Also, if your test program does not wait for the thread to start or to stop, you may not notice the canceling happening.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static void *ThreadProc(void * arg);
static void unwind(__attribute__ ((unused)) void *arg);

int _fActive = 0;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
pthread_t    Thread;
int      nRet;

    nRet = pthread_create(&Thread, NULL, ThreadProc, NULL);
    printf("MAIN: waiting for thread to startup...\n");
    while (_fActive == 0)
        nanosleep(&(struct timespec){ 0, 0}, NULL);
    printf("MAIN: sending cancel...\n");
    nRet = pthread_cancel(Thread);

    printf("MAIN: waiting for thread to exit...\n");
    while (_fActive)
        nanosleep(&(struct timespec){ 0, 0}, NULL);

    printf("MAIN: done\n");
    return 0;
}

static void unwind(__attribute__ ((unused)) void *arg)
{
    // do some cleanup if u want
    printf("THREAD: unwind (all threads, canceled or normal exit get here)\n");
    _fActive = 0;
}

static void *ThreadProc(void * arg)
{
    pthread_cleanup_push(unwind, arg);
    // optional : pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
    printf("THREAD: Enter Sleep\n");
    _fActive = 1;
    sleep(1000000);
    printf("THREAD: Exit Sleep (canceled thread never gets here)\n");
    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);

    printf("THREAD: Exit (canceled thread never gets here)\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

Program output:

```
MAIN: waiting for thread to startup...
THREAD: Enter Sleep
MAIN: sending cancel...
MAIN: waiting for thread to exit...
THREAD: unwind (all threads, canceled or normal exit get here)
MAIN: done
```

Notice how the cancel blows out of ThreadProc at the cancel point sleep() and executes only the unwind() function.

Comment: You can use `pthread_cancel` just fine without cleanup handlers, but if you've allocated resources that should be freed, doing so would result in a resource leak.

Comment: I'm sure you are right when it comes to this subject.  I had previously believed that cleanup_push and pop setup the longjump that pthread_cancel invoked.  I guess you are you saying there is a default one setup by pthread_create.  Do I have it right?

Comment: At the end of the chain of cleanup handlers, the implementation-internal thread exit code (which includes thread-specific-data destructors and possibly other implementation-specific stuff) runs. If there are no cleanup handlers, execution passes directly there. Both cancellation and a call to `pthread_exit` by the thread itself have this effect.