# C++ : Modifying a timer

Tags: c++, timer

I am currently making a timer in c++ using classes.

I have the following class declaration:

```
class time
{
   int  min;
   int  sec ;
   public:
    void start()
      {
        for(int j = 0; j<60; j++)
            {
                if(min == 59)
               min = 0;
            }

            for(int k = 0; k<60; k++)
            {
            if(sec == 59)
                sec = 0;
            cout<<min<<" : "<<sec<<endl;
            sec++;
            Sleep(1000);
            system("Cls");
            }
            min++;
        }

}a;
```

So currently I can start the timer by `a.start()` I am looking for a way to stop it. Any ideas ?

*Help is appreciated :)*

Comment: To strop it you would need an external trigger. This would introduce threads...

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778361/how-to-terminate-a-sleeping-thread-in-pthread

Answer (score 1):

You'd then require a thread if you wish to terminate your timer at any given moment. I've implemented one below on a gcc 4.9.2.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

class Timer
{
public:
    Timer(uint minutes, uint seconds)
        : m_minutes(minutes)
        , m_seconds(seconds)
        , m_active(false)
    { }

    void
        start()
        {
            m_active = true;
            m_thread = std::thread([=]() 
            {
                while(m_active && (m_minutes | m_seconds))
                {
                    if(!m_seconds)
                    {
                        m_seconds = 59;
                        m_minutes = m_minutes - 1;
                    }

                    std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << m_minutes   << "m" << " "
                              << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << m_seconds-- << "s" << std::endl;
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
                }
            });
        }

    void
        stop()
        {
            m_active = false;
            m_thread.join();
        }

private:
    std::thread m_thread;
    uint        m_minutes;
    uint        m_seconds;
    bool        m_active;
};

int main( )
{
    Timer t(0, 10);

    t.start();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(7));
    t.stop();

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
00m 10s
00m 09s
00m 08s
00m 07s
00m 06s
00m 05s
00m 04s
```

`t.stop()` successfully terminates the timer at the 7th second (triggered by the thread within the main).